# how to destruct a key pair object

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to destruct a [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) object with one single `[key, value]` pair, as example:

```
var v = { foo: 'bar'};

function f({key, value}) {
   console.log('key is ' + key);
   console.log('value is ' + value);
}

f(v);
```

This example should print:

```
key is foo
value is bar
```

but it's actually printing:

```
key is undefined
value is undefined
```

How can I achieve this? Note: key names can vary.

Comment: You can't get the key and the value by destructuring, as far as I'm aware; there's no syntax to destructure an unknown key. You could do `f({ foo })` to get the value `'bar'`, but if key names vary destructuring won't work.

Comment: `Map` (the link) or `object` (the example)?

Comment: key pair object (the example)

Comment: @jonrsharpe i'm trying to use it in a `reduce` which receives an array of key pair values and in each iteration I'm trying to destruct current element, but sadly `key` names vary

Comment: Then why the link to a different collection type which is only available in ES6 and above? O.o

Comment: To make sure people understand that I’m not talking about map function

Comment: @jonrsharpe This comment should be the accepted answer imho. Thanks.

Answer (score 15):

Not sure you can destructor key / values directly inside the parameters.

But you could do it inside the function..

eg.

```js
const v = { foo: 'bar'};

function f(o) {
   const [key, value] = Object.entries(o)[0];
   console.log('key is ' + key);
   console.log('value is ' + value);
}

f(v);
```

Answer (score 6):

You could use [`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) for getting the entries of the object, which returns a key value array for each entry.

```js
function f(object) {
    for (var [key, value] of Object.entries(object)) {
        console.log('key is ' + key);
        console.log('value is ' + value);
    }
}

f({ foo: 'bar' });
```

Answer (score 2):

```
let foo = {foo: 'bar'}
let [key, value] = Object.entries(foo).flat();

console.log(key);
console.log(value);
```

Comment: There's an opportunity to explain the use of `flat()` here, which may or may not be appropriate for a given situation.

Answer (score 0):

This should work for objects with multiple properties too.

```js
var object = { foo: 'bar', food: 'pizza'};

function f(object) {
  // get an array of all keys
  let keys = Object.keys(object); 
  
  // iteratate over this array 
  keys.forEach(key => {
    // output the current key and associated value
   let property = object[key];
    console.log('key is ' + key);
    console.log('value is ' + property);
  });
}

f(object);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var v = { foo: 'bar'};

function f(obj) {
 var pair = Object.entries(obj)[0];
  console.log('key is ' + pair[0]);
  console.log('value is ' + pair[1]);
}

f(v);
```

Answer (score -1):

Not sure this is what you're looking for, but `Object.keys()` does do the trick.

```js
var v = { foo: 'bar'};

function f(o) {
   console.log('key is ' + Object.keys(o)[0]);
   console.log('value is ' + o[Object.keys(o)[0]]);
}

f(v);
```